# Select TOP x Rows in SSDT not SSMS

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

When using SSDT what I miss most is the ability to script the select statement of the top x rows like in SSMS. 
Does anyone know if it's possible to turn that on somehow by an powertool or extension that enables the "Script As" functionality in SSDT?

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click a database in the SQL Server Object Explorer (part of SSDT) and choose "New Query..." to get a query window. From there you can write and execute any query you like.

I've also got Redgate's SQL Prompt installed (I work for them), so typing "st100" gets me a top X query quickly -- the built-in intellisense may have something similar.

Comment: I know but it used to be a extension that you could install on SSDT that you would get the "Script as" menu on tables so you could get a SELECT {field, field ..... } from {table} automatically for you like you do in SSMS

Comment: Ah, sorry -- I misunderstood, It's still not quite what you're looking for, but Jamie Thomson describes writing custom code snippets for SSDT in http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2013/04/22/creating-your-own-sql-snippets-in-ssdt.aspx

Comment: I know but it wont know the table I want, nor it will show all colums